# Generate java beans dynamically

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, servlets

I am working on feature where a SQL editor is provided to the user in the web application,whatever the query user writes data should be fetched from DB and displayed on web page.

Problem:
To display the data in UI, i need to know what are all the properties user has selected and create beans based on that dynamically and pass the list of beans to UI.

How beans can be created dynamically at run time when schema is unknown?

Edit 1: Based on some search i have come across [DynaBean](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html) from Apache [BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/overview-summary.html), is it useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can to see JAVA Frame for JFinal。
https://github.com/jfinal/jfinal